# Irrlicht Human Mesh Animation

Tags: animation, mesh, irrlicht

does anybody know how anime(move) Human body Parts in Irrlicht.

I only found Animathion for the whole mesh.

I´m using makehuman.org mesh and want only to move the hand or the leg in irrlicht. There are riggins and bones in the mesh but I dont know how to move them in Irrlicht.

pls help a noob.
thx in advance

Comment: You know, on this website, when you get help, you mark an answer as the accepted answer. From the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask):> This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (And if you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)

Answer (score 2):

With a quick google search, you would have found [this wiki page](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.HowToUseTheNewAnimationSystem)…

All you need to know is the names of the *bones* of your mesh and get them as [`IBoneSceneNode`](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1scene_1_1_i_bone_scene_node.html)s using [`IAnimatedMeshSceneNode`](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1scene_1_1_i_animated_mesh_scene_node.html)'s [`getJointNode`](http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/docu/classirr_1_1scene_1_1_i_animated_mesh_scene_node.html#a790a1a03ada0eb754504609d76c5fcc1) method.

A `IBoneSceneNode` can be animated and moved around like any regular scene node.